# "To generate a lot of suggestions" saying

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a way of saying when someone generates a lot of ideas in a row.

The closest I could think of is: Tim has started to throw out random ideas at the meeting.

Would "throw out" work? Are there more casual ways of expressing it?

Comment: Throw out, and random could come across as rude as it sounds like Tom has lost the plot! Brainstorm, as answered below, is a more positive term, is commonly used, and is not rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Brainstorm" seems appropriate. It's generally used in the context of a group, but there's nothing wrong with using it to describe one person's action.

In case you need a noun, *ideation* is the process of generating ideas.

"Throw out" can work, but it could also be interpreted as "discard" or "reject" if the context isn't clear.

You could also say, "Tim *offered/proposed/generated a(n) array/stream* of ideas" if "brainstorm" isn't casual enough.

As a side note, "random" implies that the ideas may be irrelevant, poor, out of context.

Answer (score 0):

***shotgun approach***

> (idiomatic) An approach in which the subject is indiscriminate and haphazard, using breadth, spread, or quantity in lieu of accuracy, planning, etc.

[Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/shotgun-approach)

At/during the meeting, Tim started to ***shotgun*** out random ideas.

---

***throw a lot of stuff on the wall and see what sticks***

> An old method of testing spaghetti was to throw a strand against the refrigerator, and if it stuck, it was ready to take out of the boiling water. This metaphor original meant as a test to see if something was done or ready or validated. However, over the years, it has morphed to mean a test to see which solution might work. Instead of "throw it against the wall," one typically hears "throw them against the wall."

> to present an idea and test the reaction.

[onlineslangdictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/throw-against-a-wall-and-see-if-it-sticks)

Tim has started to ***throw a lot of stuff at the wall to see what sticks***.

Answer (score 0):

“Table” is the formal term for what you are describing.

“Tim tabled a lot of ideas at the meeting.”

Be a little careful with ‘brainstorm’. In current usage it is positive or neutral. However, not long ago it was deeply negative and suggested something approaching a fit, nervous breakdown or even psychotic episode. You could be communicating a very different message than intended if your reader is old or has the old meaning and not the new one.